# Add>Object Menu disabled?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, interface, edit-mode

Whenever I created an object (<2.83) a properties menu would appear allowing me to change whatever about the object (ie. vertex count on a circle/cylinder, cube size, etc), but now (2.90>) the menu does still appear but it just doesn't work.

Could the update have caused this? It's a vanilla install plus I already checked the Preferences menus for anything that could be affecting it but no luck

I greatly appreciate the help!

[image: pic bellow]